# Passing Query String in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use string.format and window.location in Javascript. I want to redirect my page to a specific url and want to pass query strings in it.

If, there is any other way then this, please suggest me else inform me where am I wrong in this code.

```
// This doesn't work
function ABC() {    
var v1 = String.format("Page1.aspx?id={0}&un={1}", Id, "name");
                window.location = v1;
}

// This works
function ABC() {    
    window.location = String.format("Page1.aspx?id=" + Id);
    }
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you'd like to pass the query-strings from the current page to another page during redirect?

Comment: `String.Format` is a C# function, not javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ABC() {    
  window.location = "Page1.aspx?id=" + Id + "&un=name";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
window.location.assign('/Page1.aspx?id='+ Id + '&un='+'name');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `String.format` in JavaScript, you can either build your own function to format a string or use the normal syntax with the `+` operator.

Here's a solution:

```
// Build your own format function
function formatString(s) {
    for (var i=1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        s.replace(new RegExp('\\{'+(i-1)+'\\}', 'g'), arguments[i]);
    }

    return s;
}

function ABC() {
    var queryString = formatString("Page1.aspx?id={0}&un={1}", Id, "name");
    window.location.assign(queryString);
}

// Or use the reular syntax:
function ABC() {
   window.location.assign("Page1.aspx?id="+ Id + "&un=name");
}
```